# How to properly insert from stdin in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

normal insert:

```
insert into tfreeze(id,s) values(1,'foo');
```

I tried the following ways, both not working:

```
copy tfreeze(id,s ) from stdin;
1 foo
\.
```

---

```
copy tfreeze(id,s ) from stdin;
    1 'foo'
    \.
```

Only a few questions related from stdin in stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Postgres+Insert+statements+from+stdin

--
error code:

```
ERROR:  22P02: invalid input syntax for type integer: "1 foo"
CONTEXT:  COPY tfreeze, line 1, column id: "1 foo"
LOCATION:  pg_strtoint32, numutils.c:320
```

I get code from this(https://postgrespro.ru/education/books/internals) book.
code source: https://prnt.sc/eEsRZ5AK-tjQ
So far I tried:
`1, foo`,   `1\t'foo'`,   `1\tfoo`

Comment: I execute inside psql, already logged in.

Comment: The error message yields the solution: your columns aren't separated with a tab character (`\t` or ASCII 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to use `psql` for that (you are already doing that).

You get that error because you use the default `text` format, which requires that the values are separated by tabulator characters (ASCII 9).

I recommend that you use the CSV format and separate the values with commas:

```
COPY tfreeze (id, s) FROM STDIN (FORMAT 'csv', FREEZE);
1,foo
\.
```

Comment: I try to replicate this (https://prnt.sc/5o_HBxHfLda5) freeze on boot then failed at copy command.

Comment: I tried `1\tfoo`     `1\t"foo"`    `1\t'foo'` both 3  not working.

Comment: `\t` is no tabulator character. Not sure what you mean with this weird "freeze on boot" text, but you sure can add `FREEZE` to the options.

Comment: `copy tfreeze(id,s ) from stdin with freeze ;`  is valid clause. It's just stdin input have problem. 
But `copy tfreeze(id,s ) from stdin with freeze (format 'csv') ;` is invalid clause.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bobgebpb07ctCM-Jk9XBxmY8k9CZkorn/view?usp=sharing google translated. page  163.

Comment: Try not to be dense.